# Errors from custom FieldItemList::getConstraints() displayed next to every single property

Tags: entities

**Summary**

Errors set by constraints on custom field types appear next to every single property by default.

We can use the `::errorElement()` method on the widget to place errors that come from the `::getConstraints()` method of the field **item**.

However, errors that come from `::getConstraints()` in a custom field item **list** will not go through `::errorElement()`. How can we reasonably place them?

**Details**

My original problem ist very complicated. I've drastically simplified it to show only what's essential. We start with a very simple custom field type with 2 number properties.

```
class YearRangeType extends FieldItemBase {
  public static function propertyDefinitions($field_definition) {
    $properties['start'] = DataDefinition::create('integer');
    $properties['end'] = DataDefinition::create('integer');
    return $properties;
  }

  public static function schema($field_definition) {
    $schema = ['columns' => [
      'start' => ['type' => 'int',],
      'end' => ['type' => 'int',],
    ],];
    return $schema;
  }

  public function isEmpty() {
    $start = $this->get('start')->getValue();
    $end = $this->get('end')->getValue();
    return !($start || $end);
  }
}
```

We define a custom `FieldItemList` for it that adds a simple validation: checking if at least 2 items are present.

```
class YearRangeItemList extends FieldItemList {
  public function getConstraints() {
    $constraints = parent::getConstraints();
    $constraints[] = $this->getTypedDataManager()
      ->getValidationConstraintManager()
      ->create('Count', [
        'min' => 2
      ]);
    return $constraints;
  }
}
```

When I try to save only one item, the field will look like this:

[image: Errors appear next to every single property.]

If the errors would result from `YearRangeType::getConstraints(), we could use the`errorElement()` method of the widget to place them.

However, the Drupal core class `WidgetBase` does deliberately not pass errors set by the item list to `errorElement()`, see [these lines in the Drupal core code](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/bd90f56f50ca792506465fbd0af5d370c53005e1/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/WidgetBase.php#L471) (version 8.8.1).

How else should we place them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can place the errors with three modifications in the widget class.

First, we add the empty form element `non_field_errors` we can attach the errors to.

```
class YearRangeWidget extends WidgetBase {
    ...
    public function form($items, &$form, $form_state, $get_delta = NULL) {
        $formElement = parent::form($items, $form, $form_state, $get_delta);
        $formElement['non_field_errors'] = ['#type' => 'item'];
        return $formElement;
    }
    ...
}
```

Second, in the `flagErrors` method, we collect all errors that do **not** belong to any property and call a separate method to treat them.

```
class YearRangeWidget extends WidgetBase {
    ...
    public function flagErrors($items, $violations, $form, $form_state) {
        $listViolations = [];
        foreach ($violations as $key => $violation) {
            if ($violation->getPropertyPath() === '') {
                $listViolations[] = $violation;
                $violations->remove($key);
            }
        }
        parent::flagErrors($items, $violations, $form, $form_state);
        $this->flagNonFieldErrors($items, $listViolations, $form, $form_state);
    }
    ...
}
```

Third, we define the method treating the separated errors.

```
class YearRangeWidget extends WidgetBase {
    ...
    public function flagNonFieldErrors($items, $violations, $form, $form_state) {
        $field = $items->getName();
        foreach ($violations as $violation) {
            $form_state->setError(
                $form[$field]['non_field_errors'],
                $violation->getMessage()
            );
        }
    }
    ...
}
```